# MySQL query to create a pivot table by joining 4 different table

Tags: mysql, matrix, pivot-table

I have 4 mySQL tables namely Exams, Marks, Student and Subject. Sql with data is provided below. I need the output like below screenshot.

[image]

Marks is calculated from all Marks added together for the particular subject and student pair with their proper Weightage in Percentage (Exams with 0 Weightage are ignored)

I tried using the below query but the result didn't gave the cumulative marks so need help.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
               CONCAT('MAX(IF(sj.SubjectId = ''', SubjectId,''', pa.Marks, NULL)) AS ',SubjectId)
              ) INTO @sql
FROM Subject;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.ID, s.StudentID, s.FirstName, s.LastName, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM Student s
                  JOIN Marks AS pa 
                  ON pa.StudentID = s.StudentID AND pa.OrganizationId = s.OrganizationId 
                  JOIN Exams p
                  ON p.ExamId = pa.ExamId AND p.OrganizationId = pa.OrganizationId
                  JOIN Subject sj
                  ON p.SubjectId = sj.SubjectId AND pa.OrganizationId = sj.OrganizationId
                  WHERE p.Weightage > 0
                  GROUP BY s.ID');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Please help. [FIDDLE LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3396812b36792b2776246a45f22f0dd2)

```
CREATE TABLE `Exams` (
  `ID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `ExamId` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalMarks` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `SubjectId` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Weightage` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OrganizationId` int(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Exams`
--

INSERT INTO `Exams` (`ID`, `ExamId`, `Name`, `Date`, `TotalMarks`, `SubjectId`, `Weightage`, `OrganizationId`) VALUES
(8, 'EX_0001', 'Test 1', '2020-05-30 17:15:38.000000', 50, 'SUB_0002', 0, 116),
(9, 'EX_0002', 'Test 2', '2020-05-17 17:15:19.000000', 30, 'SUB_0001', 0, 116),
(10, 'EX_0003', 'Test 3', '2020-05-17 17:15:51.000000', 30, 'SUB_0003', 10, 116),
(11, 'EX_0004', 'Test 45', '2020-05-19 15:15:08.000000', 30, 'SUB_0001', 0, 116),
(12, 'EX_0005', 'Final Exam', '2020-05-20 15:30:53.000000', 100, 'SUB_0001', 80, 116),
(13, 'EX_0006', 'Terminal 3', '2020-05-20 15:30:03.000000', 50, 'SUB_0001', 10, 116);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Marks`
--

CREATE TABLE `Marks` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `StudentId` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ExamId` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Marks` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `OrganizationId` int(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Marks`
--

INSERT INTO `Marks` (`ID`, `StudentId`, `ExamId`, `Marks`, `OrganizationId`) VALUES
(14, 'S_100000001', 'EX_0004', 30, 116),
(15, 'S_100000001', 'EX_0003', 25, 116),
(16, 'S_100000001', 'EX_0002', 77, 116),
(17, 'S_100000003', 'EX_0003', 15, 116),
(18, 'S_100000003', 'EX_0004', 12, 116),
(19, 'S_100000003', 'EX_0001', 12, 116),
(20, 'S_100000002', 'EX_0004', 20, 116),
(21, 'S_100000002', 'EX_0003', 21, 116),
(22, 'S_100000001', 'EX_0005', 80, 116),
(23, 'S_100000002', 'EX_0005', 90, 116);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Student`
--

CREATE TABLE `Student` (
  `ID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `GradeId` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `StudentID` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `OrganizationId` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `FatherFirstName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `FatherLastName` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateOfBirth` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PlaceOfBirth` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sex` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Carnet` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `MobilePhone` bigint(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `MotherFirstName` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `MotherLastName` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `FatherMobilePhone` bigint(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MotherMobilePhone` bigint(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FatherProfession` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `MotherProfession` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Observations` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Student`
--

INSERT INTO `Student` (`ID`, `GradeId`, `StudentID`, `OrganizationId`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `FatherFirstName`, `FatherLastName`, `DateOfBirth`, `PlaceOfBirth`, `Sex`, `Carnet`, `MobilePhone`, `Address`, `MotherFirstName`, `MotherLastName`, `FatherMobilePhone`, `MotherMobilePhone`, `FatherProfession`, `MotherProfession`, `Observations`) VALUES
(21, 'G_016', 'S_100000001', 116, 'Student', 'One', '', '', '', '', 'male', NULL, 8178109047, '', '', '', 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(22, 'G_016', 'S_100000002', 116, 'Student', 'two', '', '', '', '', 'female', NULL, 0, '', '', '', 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(23, 'G_002', 'S_100000003', 116, 'Student3', 'three', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'male', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Subject`
--

CREATE TABLE `Subject` (
  `ID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `SubjectId` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Abbreviation` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `GradeId` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `OrganizationId` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `StaffId` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Subject`
--

INSERT INTO `Subject` (`ID`, `SubjectId`, `Name`, `Abbreviation`, `GradeId`, `OrganizationId`, `StaffId`) VALUES
(12, 'SUB_0001', 'English 1A', 'Eng_1A', 'G_016', 116, 'E_100000030'),
(13, 'SUB_0002', 'English 1B', 'Eng_1B', 'G_002', 116, '0'),
(14, 'SUB_0003', 'Science 1A', 'Sci_1A', 'G_016', 116, 'E_100000030');
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: What @Strawberry said. Doing pivots in SQL, especially in MySQL, is a notorious pain in the xxx neck.

Comment: After examaning your data, your query is correct. Subjet2 has no Weightage bigger than 0, what result do oyu expect

Comment: @nbk After increasing the weightage the value doesn't changes and I am sure how to do the calculation to get the cumulative marks on basis of weightage.

Comment: your weightage selects the exams that are selected, in the example 3 5 and 6 and for them you get the marks. for every student. I don't understand what you want as result, so please show us that

Comment: @nbk I updated the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a68a6145e61c5dd1a90d6d3431db0b66 with updated weightage, as you can see 'SUB_0001' has 4 exams, 3 of them are having Weightage. 'S_100000001' appeared 3 Exams with subjectid 'SUB_0001', out of which 2 Exams with ID 'EX_0002' and 'EX_0005' are having Weightage 10 and 80 so the Marks should be (10% of 77) + (80% of 80) = 71.7 But it is showing 80 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok with your last comment, your query would look like this

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>                CONCAT('SUM(IF(sj.SubjectId = ''', SubjectId,''', ROUND((pa.`Marks` * p.`Weightage` / 100),1),0)) AS ',SubjectId)
>               ) INTO @sql
> FROM Subject;
>
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.ID, s.StudentID, s.FirstName, s.LastName, ', @sql, ' 
>                   FROM Student s
>                   JOIN Marks AS pa 
>                   ON pa.StudentID = s.StudentID AND pa.OrganizationId = s.OrganizationId 
>                   JOIN Exams p
>                   ON p.ExamId = pa.ExamId AND p.OrganizationId = pa.OrganizationId
>                   JOIN Subject sj
>                   ON p.SubjectId = sj.SubjectId AND pa.OrganizationId = sj.OrganizationId
>                   WHERE p.Weightage > 0
>                  GROUP BY s.ID
>                  ORDER BY s.ID');
> #SELECT @sql;
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | StudentID   | FirstName | LastName | SUB_0001 | SUB_0002 | SUB_0003
> -: | :---------- | :-------- | :------- | -------: | -------: | -------:
> 21 | S_100000001 | Student   | One      |     71.7 |      0.0 |      2.5
> 22 | S_100000002 | Student   | two      |     72.0 |      0.0 |      2.1
> 23 | S_100000003 | Student3  | three    |      0.0 |      1.2 |      1.5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=85bf07f664d3ee6b411f5e6b9a0f5cab)*