# Is it possible to use keys as columns and values as values for a key/value database structure?

Tags: mysql, join, select, group-by, pivot

I need to query some data from a MySQL key value table but I want get a "normal" table as result with specified keys as columns.

Example of my table `USERS`:

```
ID, user_id, key,        value 
----------------------------------
1   1        first_name  Peter
2   1        last_name   Sputnick
3   2        first_name  Jan
4   2        last_name   Putgraver
5   2        country     Netherlands
```

I want this as query result:

```
ID, first_name, last_name
----------------------------
1   Peter       Sputnick
2   Jan         Putgraaf
```

Is there a good and efficient way to achieve this? Note that I don't want to include the country column in my result.

I need this because i need to join this data with data from another table and i don't want to use a sub query for each field i need. So I don't want to do something like this:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT value 
  FROM users 
  WHERE user_id = o.user_id 
    AND key = first_name),
(SELECT value 
  FROM users 
  WHERE user_id = o.user_id 
    AND key = last_name),
FROM orders o
```

Comment: Moving values to column names is "pivoting". Clearly this is going to be a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @Strawberry Please accept my sincere Happyhammer Clappyhands ™.

Comment: @Strawberry Or is that Hammerhappy Handyclaps ™? (If only I there were a Clickicon™ I wouldn't have to spell it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for thsi you must use conditional aggregation,

> ```
> CREATE TABLE USERS (
>   `ID` VARCHAR(6),
>   `user_id` VARCHAR(9),
>   `key` VARCHAR(10),
>   `value` VARCHAR(11)
> );
> ```

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO USERS
>   (`ID`, `user_id`, `key`, `value`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', 'first_name', 'Peter'),
>   ('2' ,  '1', 'last_name', 'Sputnick'),
>   ('3', '2', 'first_name', 'Jan'),
>   ('4', '2', 'last_name', 'Putgraver'),
>   ('5', '2', 'country', 'Netherlands');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT user_id
> , MAX(IF(`key` ='first_name',`value`,NULL )) fisrt_name
> , MAX(IF(`key` ='last_name',`value`,NULL )) last_name
> FROM USERS
> GROUP BY user_id;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | fisrt_name | last_name
> :------ | :--------- | :--------
> 1       | Peter      | Sputnick 
> 2       | Jan        | Putgraver
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=708befff48cf5da1e3682db5436392f3)*

If you want all keys you must use a [pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61924128/5193536)

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    id,
    max(case when key = 'fist_name' then value end) first_name,
    max(case when key = 'last_name' then value end) last_name
from users
group by id
```