# How to extract different json elements from the same table in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am querying from a table with the following format:

```
id|provider|score
--------------------------------
1 |  att     | '{"attscore":300}'
1 |  verizon | '{"verizonscore":299}'
2 |   att    | '{"attscore":200}'
3 |  verizon | '{"verizonscore":155}'
```

I am trying to get a table that looks like the following:

```
id|attscore|verizonscore
-------------------------
1  |  300   |    299
2  |  200   |    null
3  |  null  |    155
```

Note that used to json in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `provider` VARCHAR(7),
>   `score` VARCHAR(22)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `provider`, `score`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'att', '{"attscore":300}'),
>   ('1', 'verizon', '{"verizonscore":299}'),
>   ('2', 'att', '{"attscore":200}'),
>   ('3', 'verizon', '{"verizonscore":155}');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> id,
> GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN provider = 'att' THEN `score`->"$.attscore" ELSe NULL END) attscore
> ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN provider = 'verizon' THEN `score`->"$.verizonscore" ELSe NULL END) verizonscore
> FROM table1
> GROUP BY id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | attscore | verizonscore
> -: | :------- | :-----------
>  1 | 300      | 299         
>  2 | 200      | null        
>  3 | null     | 155
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f821134d8d2334c11730e33ecef8ec4)*

This works with a fixed number of column quite well, if you have much more of these you need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920905/mysql-query-to-create-a-pivot-table-by-joining-4-different-table/61924128#61924128)