# MySQL Cross Tab - struggling to move values that sit as rows into columns

Tags: mysql, pivot, crosstab

Using data from a Wordpress form that is presented within phpMyAdmin as:

[image]

From the image above, you'll see how it lists the values as rows rather than as columns :(
Having to use MySQL (not my preference) and am struggling to crosstab it to be the bottom table.

I have Created the Table for the values to insert into, but am getting stuck after that.

Comment: you need a pivot table like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61924128/5193536 and use a MAXC instead of a sum. and please read here why you should not post images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I think this is already solved in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql